# look back in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a  data set with customer information i.e. what a particular customer has purchased on a particular date. Now have to look at those customers who have not purchased anything in last 60 days.

```
Customer_key order_date item
001          01jan2018  cake 
001          09Apr2018  wheat
002          08Feb2017  flour
```

That's how the data set look.
I have to do it with simply SQL query.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's the type of `order_date`? Is it just a string?

Comment: order_date is date variable

Comment: So the question is: "please write code for me. I have tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas"?

Comment: Question is to get those customers who have not done any transaction in the last 60 days. And I'm using oracle .

Comment: Don't ask for others to write code for you. Add the SQL you have tried.

Comment: Hint: When a customer didn't purchase within the last 60 days `max(order_date)` will be older than today - 60.

Comment: `I have to do it with simply SQL query` then do it.. :)

Comment: #MSPARER I have googled and not getting it..I tried in SAS as well 
proc sql;
create table t as
Select * from prab a where customer_key  in 
(select  customer_key from prab b where order_date between intnx("days",order_date,-60) and intnx("days",order_date,-1) and a.customer_key=b.customer_key);
Quit; But not getting the logic. So please think before you say.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your name is named `tablename`, you may try this query:

```
SELECT customer_key
FROM (
    SELECT customer_key, max(order_date) as max_date
    FROM tablename group by customer_key
) a
WHERE a.max_date < (sysdate - 60);
```